# How to iterate over every keys and values of a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io

i have created a nested dictionary from the input given in a file. Writing the input of the file below for your reference :-

name1: #(for student 1)

name2, 1

name3, 0

name4, 1
…

name2: #(for student 2)

name1, 0

name3, 0

name4, 0
… and so on for every student.

scenario of the question is, each and every student is conducting a survey yes(1)/no(0) based and noting down the response of every other student. and in the end we have to tell which student have got more yes(1) response.

*I have tried to do it by making a nested dictionary from the input from a file but now i'm stuck on how to iterate over every keys and values of nested dictionary and count which student has got maximum yes(1) responses.*

**The nested dictionary is of the form:-
{'name1': {'name2': 1, 'name3': 0, 'name4': 1}, 'name2': {'name1': 0, 'name3': 0, 'name4': 0}}**

I'm a beginner and nested dictionary is new to me but i have tried below code

```
d = {}

with open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\python\\yearbook.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.endswith(':'):
            name = line[:-1]
            d[name] = {}
        elif line:
            innername, value = line.split(',')
            d[name][innername] = int(value)


def nested_dict_pairs_iterator(dict_obj):
    ''' This function accepts a nested dictionary as argument
        and iterate over all values of nested dictionaries
    '''
    # Iterate over all key-value pairs of dict argument
    for key, value in dict_obj.items():
        # Check if value is of dict type
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            # If value is dict then iterate over all its values
            for pair in  nested_dict_pairs_iterator(value):
                yield (key, *pair)
        else:
            # If value is not dict type then yield the value
            yield (key, value)
#Loop through all key-value pairs of a nested dictionary
count = 0
for pair in nested_dict_pairs_iterator(d):
    if(pair[2]==1):
        count+=1
print(count)
```

Comment: What you want is that in your for loop at the bottom `for pair in nested_dict_pairs_iterator(d):` you can retrieve the values from the generator to get a table with the students and their notes?

Comment: i was trying to get the count for each student but i'm getting it as  a whole i.e. all yes(1) in the input. How do i separate this count for each student?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below solution could serve your purpose. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
def get_results(mydict):
    results = {}
    for key,val in mydict.items():
        for student, vote in mydict[key].items():
            if (vote == 1):
                if key in results.keys():
                    results[key] += 1
                else:
                    results[key] = 1
    return results
          
mydict = {'name1': {'name2': 1, 'name3': 1, 'name4': 1}, 'name2': {'name1': 0, 'name3': 1, 'name4': 0},'name3': {'name1': 0, 'name2': 0, 'name4': 1},'name4': {'name1': 0, 'name3': 1, 'name2': 0}}      
print(get_results(mydict))
```

output : `{'name1': 3, 'name2': 1, 'name3': 1, 'name4': 1}`

Comment: your code is giving the output in the format **{'name2': 1, 'name4': 2, 'name1': 1, 'name3': 1}** . it's printing the name of students given yes(1) response. where as it should print somewhat like this- name1: - 3(got total 3 yes responses)  name2:- 1(got total 1 yes responses)

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood the question. I have corrected it. Please see the edited answer and let me know if you have any question

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want to do, I can advise you to create a dictionary with a key for each student name, and a number that you will increment each time you get a 1

```
# Loop through all key-value pairs of a nested dictionary
student_note = {}

for pair in nested_dict_pairs_iterator(d):
    if len(pair) == 3:
        student, student2, note = pair
        if student not in student_note:
            student_note[student] = 0
        if note == 1:
            student_note[student] += 1
```

And with :

```py
d = {
    "name1": {"name2": 1, "name3": 0, "name4": 1},
    "name2": {"name1": 0, "name3": 0, "name4": 0},
}
```

I get : `{'name1': 2, 'name2': 0}`

Comment: @MayankPandey Yes sorry, I corrected it as soon as I saw the comment on the other answer,
Don't forget to accept an answer to indicate that your question has been answered!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution, just `sum` the values in the inner `dict`s for each student:

```
data = {'name1': {'name2': 1, 'name3': 1, 'name4': 1}, 'name2': {'name1': 0, 'name3': 1, 'name4': 0},'name3': {'name1': 0, 'name2': 0, 'name4': 1},'name4': {'name1': 0, 'name3': 1, 'name2': 0}}
count = {student: sum(responses.values()) for student,responses in data.items()}
print(count)
```

Outputs:

```
{'name1': 3, 'name2': 1, 'name3': 1, 'name4': 1}
```